# Perl, XML::Simple, and a troubling foreach loop

Tags: xml, perl, foreach

I'm really new to Perl and a first timer to [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML%3a%3aSimple).

I have a `foreach` loop (XML data already fed into `$xmlHash`)

```
foreach (@{$xmlHash->{$PROTEIN}->{$PEPTIDE}}) {}
```

That works 90 times when the $peptide key contains a multiple peptides. However, protein 91 (and many others after) have only a single peptide (a scalar value), which causes `perl` to throw

```
Not an ARRAY reference at C:\...
```

What is the best way to make the foreach loop also work with scalar `$PEPTIDES`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [ForceArray](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML%3a%3aSimple#ForceArray_=%3E_1_#_in_-_important) in `XML::Simple` documentation.

Comment: $xml = XMLin('Pool 1N-1.xml', ForceArray => [$PEPTIDE]); worked flawlessly. THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
XMLin($xml, ForceArray => [ $PEPTIDE ])

for (@{ $xmlHash->{$PROTEIN}->{$PEPTIDE} }) { ... }
```

Alternatively,

```
sub listify {
   return () if !defined($_[0]);
   return ref($_[0]) eq 'ARRAY' ? @{ $_[0] } : $_[0];
}

for (listify $xmlHash->{$PROTEIN}->{$PEPTIDE}) { ... }
```